# How to use jobs command and view results

Tags: jobs

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to view the list of running jobs using the jobs command yet there is no results shown and when I enter 
"man jobs" the shell responds that there is no such command available. am I doing the wrong way to view job list? and if so what would be the solution to it?

Comment: Are there any jobs running in the background? What do you mean by "jobs"? Do you mean all processes running on the system? Also, try `help jobs`, it's a shell builtin and has no manual.

Comment: Dear tredon, I didn't even know about the background jobs. Thank you very much and I  think I owe you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jobs is shell builtin,so no man but

```
help jobs
```

The use is simply

```
vi&  #vi goes in background(i know,is useseless)

jobs  #return status
jobs -p #return status and pid
%     #resume first job, vi in this case
%2    #resume second job
ctrl-z #suspend job
```

For more options and use `help jobs`

If you want to see processes

```
ps     #show process
ps -ef #sv style,all processes
ps aux #bsd style,all processes
man ps #better read
```

Comment: Thank you very much elbarna for the complete description. I owe you man.

Comment: If someone wants to have a more complete review he/she can visit :http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins